# CSS elements alignment on the page

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I am trying to write CSS using Tailwind which should display 3 elements on a page:

```
-----------------------
|       Header text   |
-----------------------
|                     |
|       An image      |
|                     |
-----------------------
|         Button      |
-----------------------
```

The layout should follow 4 rules:

1. Take all vertical space of the page
2. Header text should be fully visible, be displayed on top of the image. Could span one or several lines.
3. Button should be fully visible, be displayed on bottom of the page
4. An image should take as much space as possible

The problem is that I cannot make it work for arbitrary text length of the header.

Below I am including code in Tailwind CSS as well as link to a demo.

```
<div>
  <div class="flex h-screen flex-col bg-blue-500">
    <div class="flex h-screen flex-row overflow-hidden">
      <div class="flex grow flex-col">
        <div class="mx-4 mt-4 flex h-full max-h-[calc(100%-4rem)] flex-col justify-center align-middle">
          <div class="mx-10 mb-4 text-center text-5xl font-black text-white drop-shadow-lg">Text, should always be visible and could take just one or several lines to be displayed on the screen of the user.</div>
          <img class="max-h-[85vh] w-auto object-contain" src="https://c0.wallpaperflare.com/preview/882/54/391/animal-baby-bird-born.jpg" alt="xxx" />
        </div>
        <div class="text-cente mt-1 flex-none">
          <div class="flex flex-row items-center justify-center">
            <div class="flex cursor-pointer flex-row items-center justify-center rounded border border-white/30 bg-blue-900 px-2 py-1 font-semibold text-white/90 transition duration-150 ease-in-out hover:border-black/70 hover:bg-white hover:text-gray-800" title="Skip">
              <span>&nbsp; Button, should always be visible, below the duck</span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Demo](https://play.tailwindcss.com/XP6Mu2SIHK)

Comment: You should start by actually making this three separate _sibling_ elements. Right now, you have header text and image wrapped together into a container element, which isn't very conducive to what you want to achieve in the first place.

Comment: You want something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/k6p03tjz/ ?

Comment: @ATP Your example is good except for it doesn't work for text of variable length

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand, I think this is what you are looking for:

```html
<div class="flex flex-col h-screen bg-blue-500">
  <div class="flex-none">
    <div class="mx-10 mb-4 text-center text-5xl font-black text-white drop-shadow-lg">Text, should always be visible and could take just one or several lines to be displayed on the screen of the user.Text, should always be visible and could take just one or several lines to be displayed on the screen of the user.</div>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-grow overflow-hidden">
    <img class="object-contain w-full h-full" src="https://c0.wallpaperflare.com/preview/882/54/391/animal-baby-bird-born.jpg" alt="xxx" />
  </div>
  <div class="flex-none">
    <div class="flex flex-row items-center justify-center" style="/*! background-color: cadetblue; */">
        <div class="flex cursor-pointer flex-row items-center justify-center rounded border border-white/30 bg-blue-900 px-2 py-1 font-semibold text-white/90 transition duration-150 ease-in-out hover:border-black/70 hover:bg-white hover:text-gray-800" title="Skip">
          <span>&nbsp; Button, should always be visible, below the duck</span>
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

On the image tag, remember that you can choose either to `object-contain` or `object-cover` this section. You have not specified which you want. So I have just followed your example and kept it object-contain.

If you need any gap between the items you can add this to the first element's class by adding for example `gap-8`

Have a great day!

Comment: Thats is excellent, thank you so much! Accepting answer.